# Using "*" doesn't work when Uninstalling Applications in Linux Mint 20

Tags: linux-mint, apt, uninstall

I have (for example) different LibreOffice products installed and I want to remove them. I tried:

```
sudo apt purge libreoffice*
```

This had worked before uninstalling everything that was part of LibreOffice (Base, Calc, Draw, etc.) But it doesn't work now. It gives out these errors:

1. ```
   $ sudo apt purge libreoffice*

   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   E: Unable to locate package libreoffice*
   ```
2. (LibreOffice is installed, it opens fine!)

   ```
   $ sudo apt purge libreoffice/*
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   Package 'libreoffice' is not installed, so not removed
   Selected version '1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1' (Ubuntu:20.04/focal-updates [amd64]) for 'libreoffice'
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
   ```
3. ```
   $ sudo apt purge libreoffice\*
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   E: Unable to locate package libreoffice*
   ```

Using Linux Mint 20 based on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Likely this is relevant: [Problem using wildcard with apt](https://askubuntu.com/a/1218821/178692)

Comment: Yes it is thanks!